# Controlling Two.js SVG with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, svg, hammer.js, two.js

I have used `Two.js` to interpret an SVG and I am wanting to control the change of the parameters such as `linewidth`, `scale`, `rotation` and `noFill().stroke` with the multi-touch events of `Hammer.js`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohin/kq2q0xa4/) showing where I am currently at with it. This is my current Two.js interpret with some code @runspired from the Hammer.js team shared with me on their Slack channel. It's using the TouchEmulator(); to add shift functionality for a second pointer.

As you can see in the fiddle I am trying to add `letter.scale` as the `var liveScale` and I am trying to add `letter.rotation` to the `var currentRotation`. I was hoping that this would link up so that the start of the touch movement would fire the change of these variables that are defined in Two.js above. Am I silly for thinking this? Is there some form of possible fix does anybody know?

I have been using dat.GUI to control the parameters of the SVG interpreted by Two.js all along, but it's time to add touch support to this now and get rid of the sliders.

Any ideas/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hammer.js was working all along. It was because the element that was linked to Hammer was the element that had been interpreted by Two.js. Once I commented out Two.js, Hammer worked straight away controlling just the bare SVG path.

Comment: so does the jsfiddle work as intended now? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "commented out Two.js".

Comment: I'm not a Hammer.js expert but it looks like you need to pass in the Two.js dom element for the events trigger instead of the underlying SVG element which Two.js is referencing. e.g: `var manager = new Hammer.Manager(two.renderer.domElement);` Hope this helps!

Comment: I apologise, I didn't have time to update the JSFiddle as the presentation was this morning at 9am (Irish time). I disabled Two.js, so the SVG isn't being interpreted and it allowed for the touch emulation to work. I will figure out how to get it to work while the SVG is being interpreted over the next couple of weeks, I just needed to show multi-touch in my presentation for college. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: All good! Hope it went well. Just curious, if you just need touch events on an SVG.., why do you need Two.js at all?